# Printing on local label printer from the php server side, with RamyTalal/Label-Printer library

Tags: php, barcode-printing

I'm printing successfully in a local dev enviorement, running my web server on the same lan where I have the brother label printer. This is the code:

```
use Talal\LabelPrinter\Printer;
use Talal\LabelPrinter\Mode\Template;
use Talal\LabelPrinter\Command;

$stream = stream_socket_client('tcp://192.168.1.76:9100', $errorNumber, $errorString);
$printer = new Printer(new Template(1, $stream));
$printer->addCommand(new Command\ObjectCommand('referencebarcode', $product->reference ));
$printer->printLabel();
```

Work fine, but when I try on the production server, changing local ip 192.168.1.76 to public ip brother installed lan, and port 9100 forwarding to local brother IP. It's not working.

My server are running on docker container, across a nginx inverse proxy.

Can I do that? There is another way to do this? Print barcodes on my Wifi Brother, from my app running on server deployed on the internet?

Thanks a lot

Comment: From your production server can you make any socket connection as a test rather than the whole printing script... just to check that you can reach the remote network?

Comment: Hi, I try "curl -v http://MI-REMOTE-IP:9100" inside the docker container and its work sucessfully

Comment: I'd tried with this too, and all right  I can see port. if(fsockopen("myip",9100))
{
print "I can see port 9100";
}
else
{
print "I cannot see port 9100";
}'